# MySQL query with GROUP BY and ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am saving the history of Facebook likes for a page, identified by `user_id`.

Now from this table, I need to get a set representing the user_id's and their latest number of likes, based on the most recent `timestamp`.

I started off with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM facebook_log 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

But that does not do what I want because it returns the first records with the lowest `timestamps`.

I read something online about `GROUP` returning the very first records from the table.

I also understood something about `JOIN` the table with itself, but that doesn't work either, or I did something wrong.

Comment: You want to do what exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the user_id and the timestamp, you can just do

```
select f.user_id, max(f.timestamp)
from facebook_log
group by user_id;
```

if you need all the data from the table, you can do

```
select f.*
from facebook_log f
inner join (select max(timestamp) mt, user_id
            from facebook_log 
            group by user_id) m
on m.user_id = f.user_id and m.mt = f.timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I also have a table besides this for titles and configuration. Here's the eventual result:
`SELECT
 f.timestamp,
 u.title,
 f.likes
FROM
 facebook_log AS f
INNER JOIN(
 SELECT
  max(timestamp)mt,
  user_id
 FROM
  facebook_log
 GROUP BY
  user_id
)m ON m.user_id = f.user_id
AND m.mt = f.timestamp
INNER JOIN facebook AS u ON f.user_id = u.id
WHERE
 u.enabled = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the latest number of likes by using this MySQL trick:

```
select f.user_id, max(f.timestamp),
       substring_index(group_concat(f.numlikes order by f.timestamp desc), ',', 1) as LatestLikes
from facebook_log f
group by f.user_id;
```